# Storing a coverage in a JDBC database

Tags: raster, geoserver

There is another question about raster data for GeoServer.
Conditions:
 - PostGIS 2.0.3 and PostgreSQl 9.2. 
 - I followed: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic-jdbc/imagemosaic-jdbc_tutorial.html step by step.

I got an error:

```
    java -jar "c:\..\gt-imagemosaic-jdbc-11.2.jar" import  - config c:\..\osm.postgis.xml -spatialTNPrefix
tileosm -tileTNPrefix tileosm -dir c:\..\tiles\ -ext png
java.io.IOException: select srid from geometry_columns where f_table_schema=? an
d f_table_name=? and f_geometry_column=?  has no result for public,tileosm_0,geo
m
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.Import.calculateSRS(Import.java:600
)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.Import.<init>(Import.java:203)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.Import.start(Import.java:400)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.Toolbox.main(Toolbox.java:46)
```

The reference system and geometry were added by

```
psql -U postgres -d gis  -f "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\share\contrib\postgis-2.1\spatial_ref_sys.sql"
```

psql -U postgres -d gis  -f "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\share\contrib\postgis-2.1\postgis.sql"

Has anybody have an idea what is the problem? I had the same with the real database not only in this tutorial.

Comment: Can you include a link to the other "question about raster data for GeoServer", please?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the table name that you're supplying in the cmd(i.e. tile_osm#) exists in the database. I was facing the same issue because I had accidentally messed up the names.

Answer (score -1):

Check your database connection.

Had the same error caused by a typo in the connect.xml file.

So the java utility couldn't write in the database.

Comment: That is unlikely to be the reason.